# Is there a way to mimic handwriting in MS Word?

Tags: ms-office, font

I need to add some handwritten text into the text typed in MS Word. I've decided to use a handwriting font but the "handwritten" text isn't looking like really handwritten.

I guess, adding a small random character spacing and up/down shifting letters typed by handwriting font would make my text looking like really handwritten.

Is it possible to implement and how?

Comment: The easiest way is to find another handwriting font. There are many, and certainly several free ones.

Comment: I've never seen one that wasn't easily recognized as automated.  However, I have seen ads for services that will create a font based on a sample of a particular human's handwriting.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
Sub start()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim d

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add 0, 12
    d.Add 1, 12.5
    d.Add 2, 13
    d.Add 3, 13.5
    d.Add 4, 14

    Selection.Font.Name = "Segoe Print"
    current_position = 0
    current_sp = -1

    With Selection
        For Each Char In Selection.Characters
            If Char <> " " Then
                v = Int(Rnd * 50)
                i = Int(Rnd * 5)
        
                j = Int(Int(Rnd * 10) / 7)  'do we change char spacing or not
                k = Int(Rnd) * 2 - 1
        
                j1 = Int(Int(Rnd * 10) / 7)  'do we change char position or not
                k1 = Int(Rnd) * 2 - 1
        
                With Char.Font
                    .Scaling = 85 + v
                    .Spacing = -1
                    .Size = d.Item(i)
                    .Underline = False
                    .Color = RGB(30, 30, 30)

                    If IsNumeric(Char) = True Then
                        .Spacing = -2
                    End If
            
                    sp = 0
                    If current_sp = -1 Then
                        sp = k * j - 1
                    End If
                    If current_sp = 0 Then
                        sp = j - 1
                    End If
                    If current_sp = -2 Then
                        sp = -j - 1
                    End If
                    current_sp = sp
                    .Spacing = sp
            
                    pos = 0
                    If current_position = 0 Then
                        pos = k1 * j1
                    End If
                    If current_position = 1 Then
                        pos = j1
                    End If
                    If current_position = -1 Then
                        pos = -j1
                    End If
                    current_position = pos
                    .Position = pos
                End With
            End If
        Next Char
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It might be helpful to give a summary of what it does for readers who are not AppleScript savvy

Comment: @Allan I think it's Word's Visual Basic, not AppleScript. Looks like it randomly adjusts the spacing and baseline to make text look badly handwritten.

Comment: @benwiggy, I think you’re right.  I never touched VBA so my glaring mistake actually emphasizes the need for some detail around the answer,  i can see someone copy/paste that code in AppleScript and dropping  several four letter expletives trying to figure out why it didn’t work.